# How to persist MongoDB data between container restarts?

Tags: mongodb, docker

It is quite easy to run MongoDB containerised using docker. Though each time you start a new mongodb container, you will get new empty database.

What should I do in order to keep the database content between container restarts? I tried to bind external directory to container using -v option but without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old post but may be someone still need quick and easy solution...
The easiest way I found is using binding to volume.
Following that way you can easily attach existing MongoDB data; and it will live even after you destroying the container.

1. Create **volume** that points to your folder (may include existing db). In my case it's done under Windows, but you can do it on any file system:

```
    docker volume create --opt type=none --opt o=bind --opt device=d:/data/db db
```

2. Create/run docker **container** with MongoDB using that volume binding:

```
    docker run --name mongodb -d -p 27017:27017 -v db:/data/db mongo
```

Answer (score 10):

When using the official Mongo docker image, which is i.e. version `mongo:4.2.2-bionic` as writing this answer, and using docker-compose, you can achieve persistent data storage using this `docker-compose.yml` file example.

- In the official mongo image, data is stored in the container under the `root` directory in the folder `/data/db` by default.
- Map this folder to a folder in your local working directory called `data` (in this example).
- Make sure ports are set and mapped, default `27017-27019:27017-27019`.

Example of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:4.2.2-bionic
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 27017-27019:27017-27019
        volumes:
            - ./data:/data/db
```

Run `docker-compose up` in the directory where the `yml` file is located to run the `mongodb` container with persistent storage. If you do not have the official image yet, it will pull it from Dockerhub first.

Answer (score 8):

I tried using the `ehazlett/mongodb` image and it worked fine.

With this image, you can easily specify where mongo store its data with DATA_DIR env variable. I am sure it must not be very difficult to change on your image too.

Here is what I did:

`` mkdir test; docker run -v `pwd`/test:/tmp/mongo -e DATA_DIR=/tmp/mongo ehazlett/mongodb ``

notice the `` `pwd` `` in within the `-v`, as the server and the client might have different path, it is important to specify the absolute path.

With this command, I can run mongo as many time as I want and the database will always be store in the `./test` directory I just created.

Comment: This is the approach I took as well for MySQL/Postgres in docker v0.5.x.  Not sure if 1.0 will have different solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Guillaume! It worked. Just one more note for Vagrant users like me: do not put mongo directory inside /vagrant directory on virtual machine, mongo can't lock files in that directory and will exit immediately.

Comment: Does this work on windows boot2docker? I tried but it returns an error  ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files and never starts

Comment: @DanMendes To make it work under boot2docker, you might need to reduce the size of the allocated database files:
docker run -v /data:/data --name mongodb -d mongo mongod --smallfiles

Comment: Nice trick with the pwd. Very useful for running the same image against multiple apps in development too.